# How to load a web page hosted using a subdomain (https://example.example.net) inside the task pane in a outlook adding?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, office365-apps

I am trying to load an external webpage inside the office outlook add-in. It is loading properly inside the task pane when I am using a URL without a subdomain(https://example.net) in the desktop settings section in manifest.xml.

This works fine

```
       <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://example.net/?mobileapp=true/#/outlook"/>
       <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
 </DesktopSettings>
```

I have changed the  tag as mentioned in the doc to match subdomains as shown below. But no luck. the new url is loading inside a separate browser window

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://example.domain.net</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://example.net</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://example.domain.net/?mobileapp=true/#/outlook"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
```

The entier manifest.xml is given below Can someone tell me what's missing here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>55541d9d-dc69-4aa3-8015-35f93ad19b83</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>ExampleWebsitename</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="ExampleWebsitename"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="New Creates tasks from emails"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.ExampleWebsitename.com"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <!-- <AppDomain>https://release.ExampleWebsitename.net</AppDomain> -->
    <AppDomain>https://ExampleWebsitename.net</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://release.ExampleWebsitename.net/?mobileapp=true/#/outlook"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">

                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>

              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://release.ExampleWebsitename.net/?mobileapp=true/#/outlook"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="ExampleWebsitename Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Mobile View Create Task"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">

                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>

                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>

          <MobileFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
              <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="mblTaskPaneBtn">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.25x25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.25x25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.25x25" />

                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.32x32" />

                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.48x48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.48x48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="ExampleWebsitename-logo.48x48" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>

              </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.25x25" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-25.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.48x48" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-48.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="ExampleWebsitename-logo.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ExampleWebsitename-logo-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://release.ExampleWebsitename.net/?mobileapp=true/#/outlook"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="ExampleWebsitename Outlook Add-in"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="New Create Task"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: In which Platform are you facing this issue(OWA, Windows, Mac, Mobile)?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I am using Windows machine and Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14131.20278) 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with https and http protocol adding. We had to add separate URLs in both Http and Https for the same domain inside Appdomain and the problem was solved. We also used a tool called fiddler to get any other inside routings in the domains.